Expo CameraView not scanning barcodes
While switching from expoBarcodeScanner to expo CameraView the function of scanning codes stopped working. The CameraView opens up correctly, the permission is indeed granted but while trying to scan any code, nothing happens, the handleBarCodeScanned is not hitted.
CameraView Modal:
<Modal
    visible={modalVisible}
    transparent={false}
    animationType="slide"
  >
    <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
      <CameraView
        style={{ width:'100%', height:'100%' }}
        barcodeScannerEnabled
        onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
        barcodeScannerSettings={{
          barcodeTypes: ["ean13"],
        }}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.closeButton} onPress={() => setModalVisible(false)}>
        <Text style={styles.closeButtonText}>Close Scanner</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  </Modal>

Handling:
const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
console.log('hitted');
setScanned(true);
setModalVisible(false);
Alert.alert(`Bar code type ${type} -> ${data}`);

};
And working part with permissions:
const openScanner = async () => {
console.log(cameraPermission?.status);

if (cameraPermission?.status !== PermissionStatus.GRANTED) {
  const { granted } = await requestCameraPermission();
  if (!granted) {
    Alert.alert('Camera permission is required to use the barcode scanner.');
    return;
  }
}

setScanned(false);
setModalVisible(true);

};

That's actually a typo.
Before:
onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}

After:
onBarcodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarcodeScanned}

